# Change background image after animation on hover of another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to animate the logo above my nav if you hover over the `li` elements. The animation (an X flip) should reveal another logo based on the `li` being hovered on, then Xflip back to the original when no longer focused. The issue seems to be that the `li`'s are buried in the `nav` + `ul` and the logo is in a `div` outside that scope and attached as a background image to the `a` (see below):

```
<section id="header">
            <div class="logo"><a href="/"></a></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="a" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="b" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="c" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="d" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</section>
```

I tried doing something like `nav > ul > li:hover ~ .logo > a {..changebG..}` but that wasn't working out. Is there a CSS way to go about this?

*I also attempted JQuery, but am far less proficient in that.*

Comment: This cannot currently be done in CSS as none of the browsers currently support Parent methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you can't change the background of the logo when hovering on the list items.

However, an option may be to place a different logo over the top of the original one?  This will only work in certain situations, such as if the logos are the same size and not transparent (so you can see the other logo below).

You can create a pseudo element on the `<a>` which changes opacity on hover, so it covers the original logo.

Basic Concept:

```
li a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

li a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

li a.a:before {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x50/ff0000");
  top: 0;
}

li a.b:before {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x50/000000");
  top: 0;
}

li a.c:before {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x50/0066cc");
  top: 0;
}

li a.d:before {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x50/ffffcc");
  top: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OwUveHA/1/edit)**

Comment: Much appreciated. Do you think it would be cleaner to do it in JQuery, since I need to trigger both the animation and swap the images at the same time? Unfortunately the logos are different sizes and transparent. Only their height is the same.

Comment: With differing images I suspect jQuery (or JavaScript) may be the way to go.  You only need to toggle a class on the logo or header div depending on which list item is hovered

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using only CSS3. CSS3 does not allow you to reference parent elements based on a hover of the child element. You'll need to use JavaScript for this.

Hopefully browsers will soon support the parent selector that is featured in the new CSS4 documentation

Comment: It is possible to do with the new CSS4 selectors that will soon be implemented, however, browser support is very very minimal right now. Also JavaScript is needed not jQuery, jQuery is simply a JavaScript Library.

Comment: That is correct. I change the answer to reference CSS3 and JS.